# Symfony2 - one form for all entities in table

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I will try to describe my problem as simple as possible.

I have an app where user can have one scheduled event per day in whole month. (one event per day * 31 (number of days in march) = 31 events)

```
class Schedule extends Day
{
    use Timestampable;
    use Bleamable;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * FOSUserBundle...
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $day;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EventType")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="event_type", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $eventType;
 (...)
}
```

I have created two forms types for it, one for editing schedule:

```
class ScheduleType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('user')
            ->add('day')
            ->add('eventType', TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
            ])
            ;
    }
}
```

And one with form collection:

```
class ScheduleMultiType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('schedule', CollectionType::class, [
                'type' => new ScheduleType(), 'allow_add' => true
            ])
            ->add('submit', 'submit')
            ;
    }
```

Class controller:

```
public function MonthlyEditAction($year, $month)
{
    $date = new \DateTime(sprintf('%d-%02d-01', $year, $month));

    //array of days
    $dates = $this->get('app.calendar_manager')->getDaysPeriod($date);

    $scheduleEnt = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Schedule')
        ->getSchedule([
            'start' => new \DateTime('2016-03-01')
            'end' => new \DateTime('2016-03-31')
        ]);

    $userList = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
        ->findAll();

    $test['schedule'] = $scheduleEnt;

    $form = $this->createForm(new ScheduleMultiType(), $test, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('admin_holiday_create'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'calendarDate' => $date,
        'days' => $dates,
        'userList' => $userList
    );
}
```

and in twig:

```
{% for useraa in userList %}
    <tr>
    {% for asd in form.schedule %}
        {% if asd.user.vars.value == useraa.id %}


            {% for day in days %}
                {% if day.date|date('d') == asd.day.vars.value.day %}
                    <td>
                        {{ scheduleMacro.monthly_td_inputBox(day,asd) }}
                    </td>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to display all users with their schedules like this:

```
user |   1  |   2   |   3  | ...  |  31  |
u1   | 8-16 | 15-23 | 8-16 | ...  | 8-16 |
u2   | 9-17 | 16-00 | 7-15 | ...  | 8-16 |
u3   | 6-14 | 13-22 | 6-14 | ...  | 8-16 |
u4   | 5-13 | 13-22 | 9-17 | ...  | 2-10 |
```

Now my problem:

I know that this is ugly solution (twig, looping for all users and schedules) but I really don't know how to achieve it in the "right" way...

Second, now it tooks 
[image]
How to speed up? The problem is due to schedule entities. If I load less data it is faster but I need to load whole month for all users...

Comment: So, one user can have only one scheduled event for one date within one month, right? Can you have multiple events within one date from different users?

Comment: @tftd One user can have only one event in current day. Multiple users can have the same event in the same day (or different)  but also only one event per day

Comment: I see. Well what I'd do is I'd rather select all events within the date range (i.e. 01-31) and display it as a calendar. Once the user clicks on a certain date, a modal would appear (or whatever other UI way you think of) would make an ajax request which would then return the users for that date. If you **MUST** have it your way, you should probably use Redis for this and pull the records from there.

Comment: Don't use `findAll()`(`$userList = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findAll();`). If you have a lot of users it's an overkill for your server because it will try to fetch all at ones. Instead use QueryBuilder to build the queries. You can use some kind of [pagination](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle) to paginate users list based on the query and not objects. Using `QueryBuilder` you can also do `joins` to fetch all data in a single query because, for example, doing in twig:`{{ schedule.user }}` will produce additional `SELECT` statements for schedule's user.

Comment: @takeit I've tried with `QueryBuilder` but it won't help